# Redirection through a proxy with IE<11

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, proxy, redirect

I'm stuck for days on a problem that seems very specific to some version of IE and the use of a proxy.
My ASP MVC 5 app authenticate with an Ajax request. If the request is successful, a redirection to the main page is triggered by assigning the url of the main page to *window.location.href*. This works fine.

Now, the client (people) uses a Kerberos proxy and IE8/9. The redirection works fine when IE is not configured to use a proxy. Then I configured the proxy with the same parameters on both FF and IE8. I also added an entry in their exceptions' list to exclude the IP of the IIS server on which my application is deployed.
It still works fine with FF, but not with IE8/9. When using the proxy, the main page is never displayed. I only get a blank page. All the code behind the page seems to be there though. But IE 8 seems not to be willing to interpret the Javascript. I didn't test it myself, but the technician I'm in contact with told me there was no problem with IE 11.

I unsuccessfully tested many of the suggestions here : https://code.google.com/p/html5security/wiki/RedirectionMethods

It's only recently that I replaced the usual login through a form post with this ajax version. The previous version redirected because of the controller returning this :

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Main", new { area = "" });
```

It worked despite the use of a proxy.
How technically different is that kind of redirection from the redirection described hereabove?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it wasn't a problem of redirection.

It originally seemed like the redirection was the most probable place where 
the problem could lurk. I did many tests, and after I ran out of ideas, I started considering other portions of the code. I started to look for any portion of the code that had changed as compared to the previous version the client had, and I prepared myself to systematically test even parts that seemed very unlikely to cause any problem, even if it that could look "stupid"... and I quickly found a solution !

The following lines simply made IE stop the interpretation of the page :

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/Content/Images/Logo/gapLogo2014.png" />
<!--[if IE]>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Content/Images/Logo/gapLogo2014.png" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<![endif]-->
```

One of these two link tags is enough to produce the issue. And it is still true that the problem only appears with IE 8/9 when it is configured to use a proxy, and even if IE's exclusion list contains the IP of the web server.

I couldn't find the root cause. I just eliminated this factor. This client won't see a favicon, not a big deal.